# Setting variable to target all divs with same Class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When selecting a class with querySelectorAll i get an uncaught error
Uncaught TypeError: b.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
at overlaps
is there a way to fix that?

```js
function overlaps(a, b) {
    a = document.getElementById('char');
    b = document.querySelectorAll('.enemy');
    const rect1 = a.getBoundingClientRect();
    const rect2 = b.getBoundingClientRect();
    const isInHoriztonalBounds =
      rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width && rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x;
    const isInVerticalBounds =
      rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height && rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y;
    const isOverlapping = isInHoriztonalBounds && isInVerticalBounds;
    return isOverlapping;
  }
```

I have div being generated with an ID 'enemy' and want to detect overlapping with my div ID "char", but the function only targets the first div with ID 'enemy'(the console log(overlaps) fires only on the first div with ID'enemy' overlapping with ID 'char'). Applying a class to the div with ID'enemy' and selecing getElementsByClassName returns
'TypeError: b.getBoundingClientRect is not a function at overlaps'.
Is there a way to select all divs with the same ID to detect overlapping?

```js
function generateObstacles() {
  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  }
  let randomTime = Math.random() * 2000;
  let obstaclePos = 100;
  const obstacle = document.createElement('div');
  obstacle.classList.add('character');
  obstacle.classList.add('enemy');
  obstacle.classList.add('pixelart');
  obstacle.id = 'enemy';
  document.querySelector('.bg').appendChild(obstacle);
  let obsprite = document.createElement('img');
  obsprite.src = './sprites/chars/spritesheet1.png';
  obsprite.style.height = '576px';
  obsprite.style.width = '384px';
  obsprite.id = 'mainchar';
  obstacle.appendChild(obsprite);
  obstacle.style.left = obstaclePos + '%';
  obstacle.style.top = getRandomInt() + '%';

  let timerId = setInterval(function () {
    if (overlaps()) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      console.log('overlaps');
    }
    obstaclePos -= 1;
    obstacle.style.left = obstaclePos + '%';
    obsprite.classList.add('faceleft');
    obsprite.classList.add('animation');
  }, 150);
  setTimeout(generateObstacles, randomTime);
  function overlaps(a, b) {
    a = document.getElementById('char');
    b = document.getElementById('enemy');
    const rect1 = a.getBoundingClientRect();
    const rect2 = b.getBoundingClientRect();
    const isInHoriztonalBounds =
      rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width && rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x;
    const isInVerticalBounds =
      rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height && rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y;
    const isOverlapping = isInHoriztonalBounds && isInVerticalBounds;
    return isOverlapping;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ids have to be unique. If you elements with the same id, then use a class instead.

Comment: i thought that was correct, unfortunately applying a class and selecting "getElementsByClassName" returns 'TypeError: b.getBoundingClientRect is not a function at overlaps'.

Comment: class is the correct property to assign a repeating value. ID's are unique (or supposed to be). the point of that is the id is WHICH enemy are you targeting - so it needs to be unique. you target an id with document.getElementById() which will return 1 item. or document.querySelectorAll() to get all elements of a single type/class/conditional... like the class of enemy :)

Comment: I don't actually see any `getElementsByClassName` in your code, but, remember it returns an array of elements.

Comment: @Leo i understand and have added the getElementsByClassName and recieved an error. How can i apply the array to the overlaps function?

Comment: Let's suppose you do: `b = document.getElementsByClassName(...)`, then you should do `b[0].getBoundingClientRect` (if there is a single element), as `b` is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Andreas has pointed out in a comment ids should be unique. When you use:

```
 b = document.getElementById('enemy');
```

the system will (most likely) find the first instance of id enemy and stop there.

If you convert all the enemies to have class enemy then you can do:

```
  let enemies = document.querySelectorAll('.enemy');
```

Note: this gives you a collection of all the elements it's found with class="enemy" - the syntax of the selector is the same as you'd use in CSS, hence the . before enemy to indicate it's looking for things with that class.

You can then step through enemies as though it were an array (it isn't exactly, but some things work like `for (let i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++)` so the ith enemy element is enemies[i]

Comment: Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.enemy')); is what I would recommend :)

Comment: this worked for detecting overlap for all the new enemy classes like you suggested, unfortunately they have stopped moving and seem to be detecting the edge of the screen as overlap but this has furthered my progress greatly